# What is the twitter approval process for an application?

Tags: twitter, deployment

Myself and two others have developed a desktop app and one feature is that the app posts to twitter after doing some oauth. I know that there are rate limits applied for each application [see here](https://dev.twitter.com/faq#6) and I've also read through the terms [here](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/terms/agreement). The only time I see it mentioned is  [in regard to xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/xauth).
So I'm wondering if there is an approval process to go through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ordinary applications that use standard OAuth, there is no approval process; your application works as soon as you create it via the Twitter website.

Once upon a time, Twitter applications could authenticate with Basic Auth; a username and a password.  Twitter disabled that permanently a few years ago and provided XAuth as a way for application developers to transition their applications from Basic Auth to OAuth without requiring their users to re-authenticate their applications.

XAuth remains, but you need to be able to make the case that your application requires it and that OAuth is not possible for your use case.

So, just implement OAuth and there is no approval process for you to worry about.